# How to apply multiline ellipsis without using -webkit-line-clamp

Tags: html, css

Here I have content in p tag which loads dynamically. I want to apply text ellipsis after specific line(e.g show text ellipsis to 4th line if content is longer)

```css
  p {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Multiline Ellipsis</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yous should read these articles, they give a lot of different techniques on how to make a line-clamp: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the line-height to a known value (1em per eg.) and use that value to cut the text after the required number of lines (4 em in your case).
After that, you could add an ellipsis in pure CSS using the `::after` pseudo-element.

```css
p {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p::after {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Multiline Ellipsis</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```